# draw lines in front of nodes rather than behind them

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a thick semi-transparent arrow path in front of nodes, but it seems like I'm stuck drawing behind them:

[image]

How can I draw a path in front of the nodes?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, shadows, positioning}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{vhighlight}{RGB}{85,170,0}
\definecolor{vhighlight2}{RGB}{240,255,224}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm, 
       blockcolors/.style={
        % The rest
        thick,draw=black,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=black!10,
        font=\sffamily\small
    },
    block/.style={
        % The shape:
        rectangle, minimum size=6mm, minimum width=12mm, minimum height=10mm,
        node distance=5mm,
        blockcolors,
        drop shadow
    },
       every label/.style={
        font=\sffamily\scriptsize
    },
    every node/.style={
        font=\sffamily\small
    },
    >=latex
    ]
\node (A) [block, label={below:block 1}] {A};
\node (B) [block, right=of A, label={below:block 2}] {B};
\node (C) [block, right=of B, label={below:block 3}] {C};
\node (D) [block, below=of C, label={below:block 4}] {D};
\node (E) [block, below=of B, label={below:block 5}] {E};
\node (F) [block, below=of A, label={below:block 6}] {F};
\draw [->, line width=1.5mm, red, rounded corners=1mm, opacity=0.25, >=stealth] 
   (A.south) -- (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- (F) -- (F.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is correct, and the segments are drawn in the "main" layer, on top of the previously drawn boxes. The problem is that each segment starts and ends at the edges of the nodes it connects.

When you specify `(A) -- (B)`, TikZ is smart, and finds the intersection of the line which would connect the centers of these nodes, with the boundary of each node. Then it draws the line connecting the boundaries.

If you give a specific anchor for the node, this behaviour is deactivated. So you can specify for example `(A.center)--(B.center)` to have a line which connects the centers of those nodes, and thus appears "on top" of them.

In your case:

```
\draw [->, line width=1.5mm, red, rounded corners=1mm, opacity=0.25, >=stealth]
    (A.south) -- (A.center) -- (B.center) -- (C.center) --
    (D.center) -- (E.center) -- (F.center) -- (F.north);
```

will produce:

[image: Result]

You don't need to declare pgflayers to do this, by the way.

You can be more compact using a loop:

```
\draw [->, line width=1.5mm, red, rounded corners=1mm, opacity=0.25, >=stealth] 
   (A.south) \foreach \n in {A,...,F} { -- (\n.center) } -- (F.north);
```

## Update

It is possible to fix the problem with the arrow tip, whose transparency allows to "see through" the last segment. You have to draw the whole path (including arrow) in a transparency group:

```
\begin{scope}[opacity=0.25, transparency group]
\draw [->, line width=1.5mm, red, rounded corners=1mm, >=stealth] 
   (A.south) \foreach \n in {A,...,F} { -- (\n.center) } -- (F.north);
\end{scope}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 6):

I thought it would be interesting to do this using the `chains` library to place the nodes.

Although it is possible to use this library to join the chained nodes as well, in this case it is easier to join them after the chain is completed.

The drawing utilises the names which are assigned to chained nodes by default. These are of the form `chain-n` where `chain` is the name of the chain (`chain` by default) and `n` is the number of the node on the chain (starting from `1`).

The `scopes` library allows us to say

```
{

}
```

in place of

```
\begin{scope}

\end{scope}
```

This is especially useful when chaining nodes because scopes are often needed. In this case, it also comes in handy for the `transparency group`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,chains,scopes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    start chain=going right,
    node distance=5mm,
    every on chain/.style={
      thick,
      draw=black,
      top color=white,
      bottom color=black!10,
      font=\sffamily\small,
      minimum width=12mm,
      minimum height=10mm,
      drop shadow,
      label={below:block \tikzchaincount},
    },
    post join/.style={
      -stealth,
      line width=1.5mm,
      red,
      rounded corners=1mm,
    },
    every label/.style={
      font=\sffamily\scriptsize
    },
  ]
  \node [on chain] {A};
  \node [on chain] {B};
  \node [on chain] {C};
  \node [on chain=going below] {D};
  {[continue chain=going left]
    \node [on chain] {E};
    \node [on chain] {F};
  }
  {[transparency group, opacity=.25]
    \draw [post join] (chain-1.south) |- (chain-3.center) |- (chain-6.center) -- (chain-6.north);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: chained nodes with scopes]